# How to parse this json from file

Tags: java, json, simplejson

How I can parse this json file using SimpleJson lib, the format is like this:

Thank you

my file looks like this: json file with Array of Json inside;

```
 {"data":[{"host":"hostname1","port":2049,"open":"false", "info":" "},  
 {"host":"hostname1","port":2049,"open":"false", "info":" "}, 
 {"host":"hostname2","port":2049,"open":"false", "info":" "}, 
 {"host":"hostname3","port":2049,"open":"false", "info":" "}, 
 {"host":"hostname4","port":443,"open":"false", "info":" "}, 
 {"host":"hostname5","port":443,"open":"false","info":" "}, 
 {"host":"hostname6","port":61208,"open":"false","info":" "}, 
 {"host":"hostname7","port":139,"open":"false","info":" "}]}
```

my code at this moment:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
       try {
           Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("D:/file.json"));
           JSONArray jsonObject = (JSONArray) obj;
           JSONObject arr = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get(0);
           JSONArray arguments = (JSONArray) arr.get("arguments");
           System.out.println("arguments>>>>>>>>> "+arguments);
           for(int i = 0 ; i< arguments.size() ;i++){
               JSONObject object = (JSONObject) arguments.get(i);
               System.out.println(object);
               return object;
           }
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
     return null;
```

I did manually like this:

```
//data

           JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject();
           obj1.put("host", "mkyong.com");
           obj1.put("port", "555");
           obj1.put("open", "false");
           obj1.put("info", "");

           JSONObject obj2 = new JSONObject();
           obj2.put("host", "mkyong.com");
           obj2.put("port", "555");
           obj2.put("open", "false");
           obj2.put("info", "");
           JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
           list.add(obj2);

           JSONObject datajson = new JSONObject();
           datajson.put("data", list);
```

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/

Comment: I tried that, I want read from the file this simple data in the future I'm expecting huge data which I don't want to do manually.

Comment: Whether it's a large amount of data or this sample data, the ideas to read them are still the same. I don't understand your problem.

Comment: What errors did you get running your code? Where is your code?

Comment: updated with source code

Comment: Why are you doing this :  arr.get("arguments"); there are no "arguments" key

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue. How is your Question different from all the other questions about parsing JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `JSON.simple` is an old Google library. I think you need to switch to `GSON`. Here is sample code that demos how to read the given `JSON`. The Key here is that the original `JSON` object holds an array of `JSON` objects as the value of key `data`.

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JsonSimpleReaderExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        try {
            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("file.json"));
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

            JSONArray array = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("data");
            Iterator<JSONObject> iterator = array.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                JSONObject jsonObjectInJsonArray = (JSONObject) iterator.next();
                System.out.println(jsonObjectInJsonArray.get("host"));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
hostname1
hostname1
hostname2
hostname3
hostname4
hostname5
hostname6
hostname7
```

Comment: I don't want to get data, I want parse that object as it is, I don't want want to use GSON , I'm using SimpleJson in many ways I don't want to mix both Lib , I did manually like this - check post

Comment: Maybe you don't know what you want. Reading and Parsing a file almost go hand and hand.

Comment: I have gotten you to this level. If you can't figure it out from here, I don't know what to tell ya.

Comment: I want to just store value of the files inside json object to use for https post request that's my main goal :)

Comment: `Iterator<JSONObject> iterator = array.iterator();` bascially means start at the frist entry of  a `List` of `JSONObject`. In this case, start at the first element of a `JSONArray` of `JSONObjects`.