# Is there a way to make a generic JSON getPath() function?

Tags: java, json

Here is some sample JSON:

```
{
    "type": "donut",
    "batter": [
       { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
       { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" }
    ]
}
```

I want to create a caller like this (returns the batter array):

```
getPath( theJson, new String[] { "batter" })
```

or (returns Regular)

```
getPath( theJson, new String[] { "batter", 0, "type" })
```

or
getPath( theJson, "batter.0.type" })

something like this:

```
public Object getPath( JSONObject json, String[] path ) {
    Object retOb = new Object();
    for( String curPath : path ) {
       if( json.has( curPath )){
           retOb = json.get( curPath );
       }
    }   
    System.out.println( "curPath: " + (JSONObject) retOb.toString( 3 );
    return retOb;
}
```

Is this possible?  I've only been writing Java for about 6 weeks now and I'm hoping a base class can be returned and the caller to cast it to a JSONObject a JSONArray or String.  I also know that I haven't wrapped it in a try or handing errors back.  This is just enough to discuss it here.

Comment: I don't know if you are explaining your issue well. Use [`GSON`](https://github.com/google/gson) to convert the `JSON` to an array of `POJOs`  or a list of `POJOS`. From there, use plain `Java`.

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55536545/how-to-parse-this-json-from-file/55537031#55537031) can help.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70302119/show-json-in-tableview/70302970#70302970) may help, but it has a GUI component.

Comment: @SedJ601 I saw JsonPath already.  it's like that BUT I don't want to throw exceptions basically sucking them up and reporting standard errors.  I'll take a look at GSON but did want to keep the objects as real JSONObjects or JSONArrays OR at least control the errors better.

Comment: @Keith JSONObject is just another API to read JSON in java. A really, __really__ bad one. There is negative 'benefit' to keeping it 'real'. You appear to be labouring under the notion that JSONObject is more standard or well known than e.g. GSON. This is a misconception.

Comment: @rzwitserloot TY... Well I'm in an environment where all the other programmers use JSONObject so I don't want to scan the JSON over and over.  Currently there are calls to find lists from various REST calls then passes all of those to a function to combine them.  Still looking @ GSON.

Comment: The thing that I dislike about JSONObject is that it the code is too specific.  Having to know if that point is an Object, an array a string or int.  I used to have a utility function in Python that just got the requested path.  I know Java is very type specific but I'm trying to flatten JAVA to make it easier to deal with.

Comment: Post a sample `JSON` object as a `String`. Post the input to a method and then post the expected output. It just seems like yall are going about things a different way. It's hard to know based on what you posted so far.

Comment: @SedJ601 if the team made a bad choice about which API to use, you either grit your teeth and roll with it, accepting that code that interacts with it looks bad, is inflexible, hard to test/maintain, and a pain to write. _or_, you lobby the team to see the light. You don't try to write a crappy layer on topof it, that's just digging deeper.

Comment: @rzwitserloot, agreed. Given that it seems that they have already committed to an API, I would have to agree. Though, I personally would propose a change if I could "sell" the team on what I consider a better API. If the boss said no, I would do what I I do with the current API. I work for a big organization, and we use tons of old technology that most believe could be implemented better with a newer technology or newer version.

Comment: kk, TY for your input.  I'll think about that deeply the team is moving very fast with what they have and they are used to it.  My thought would have been to stuff this in a class that extends the standard JSON.  My tests would use that class and have access to this function so I could say myJSON.myFunction ( ).  So kind of showing them a better path slowly and getting what I want out of it.  In the long run the idea is to reduce the line count at the top end and make it easier to write the upper code.  I'll get that example JSON for @SedJ601.

Comment: @SedJ601 there you go, added some example JSON TY!!

Answer (score 1):

See if this can help. I did use `GSON`. This answer will not work if you can't use `GSON`. If you can't use `GSON`, let me know the exact API you are using.

### Main

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaTestAreaTwo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jsonString = 
                """
                {
                    "type": "donut",
                    "batter": [
                       { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                       { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" }
                    ]
                }
                """;
        
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Item item = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Item.class);
        System.out.println(item.getType());
        for(int i = 0; i < item.getBatter().length; i++)
        {
            Batter batter = item.getBatter()[i];
            System.out.println(batter.getId() + " - " + batter.getType());
        }
    }
}
```

### Item

```
/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class Item {
    private String type;
    private Batter[] batter;

    public Item(String type, Batter[] batter) {
        this.type = type;
        this.batter = batter;
    }

    public Batter[] getBatter() {
        return batter;
    }

    public void setBatter(Batter[] batter) {
        this.batter = batter;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Item{");
        sb.append("type=").append(type);
        sb.append(", batter=").append(batter);
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }    
}
```

### Batter

```
/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class Batter {
    private String id;
    private String type;

    public Batter(String id, String type) {
        this.id = id;
        this.type = type;
    }
    
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Batter{");
        sb.append("id=").append(id);
        sb.append(", type=").append(type);
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

### Output

```
donut
1001 - Regular
1002 - Chocolate
```

Comment: Thanks @SedJ601, I'm using JSONObject... the whole point of this is to NOT create anything specific to get the data.  I just want to call something like getPath( theJson, new String[] { "batter" }) and get what ever is there.  If it's an array of something an object or a string.  Whatever that is there.

Comment: To me, this sounds like you will need to create your own JSON parser. I am not sure of the use case of handling JSON in this manner.  JSON, in my opinion, should be used to pull data into your program and push data out of your program. You should use pure Java to manipulate the data once it's in your program. Anyway, that's my two cents. Good luck!

Comment: Understood TY, this would still use java to push and pull JSON.  The attempt is to simplify the code and not require so much getJSONObject( ) and getJSONArray() calls.  Just one line that says someJSON.getPath( ["Path1", "Path2", "Path3" ] ) and what ever is there is returned.  Or getPath( "Path1.Path2" ).  I believe GSON already does something similar "$path1.path2" style strings but I don't want to include another library.  I've treated JSON like this in Python for years but everything is a dictionary in Python.  So just a convenience.